# Cannot boot Ubuntu Live from USB

Tags: boot

So [I cannot boot into my Ubuntu or recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696604/kernel-panic-cant-enter-recovery-mode-on-ubuntu-14-04) and I tried to boot into Live Ubuntu 14.04.03 USB, but when I select first priority as USB in BIOS, and reboot system, I always get this message on black screen:

`Reboot and Select proper Boot device or insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key.`

[image]

I tried all 3 USB slots, and when I press a key I get this message over again.

I'm pretty positive it's good USB.

USB is set as first priority to boot:

[image]

Comment: Which software did you use to burn the image to USB?

Comment: @Raphael Unetbootin, using Ubuntu 14.04 in Vmware.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by creating USB using Startup Disk Creator